# Gradle with Jacoco error: finished with non-zero exit value 255

Tags: gradle, jacoco

The current environment is a parent-project with several subprojects mapped in a gradle build file.
Trying to run it with Gradle 1.12 andjacoco-plugin, the following error is observed in debug when JacocoTestReport is executed:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':selection-manager:test'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:289)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:166)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'Gradle Test Executor 1' finished with non-zero exit value 255
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:365)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultWorkerProcess.waitForStop(DefaultWorkerProcess.java:161)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.ForkingTestClassProcessor.stop(ForkingTestClassProcessor.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.processors.RestartEveryNTestClassProcessor.endBatch(RestartEveryNTestClassProcessor.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.processors.RestartEveryNTestClassProcessor.stop(RestartEveryNTestClassProcessor.java:54)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.FailureHandlingDispatch.dispatch(FailureHandlingDispatch.java:29)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.dispatchMessages(AsyncDispatch.java:132)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.access$000(AsyncDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.AsyncDispatch$1.run(AsyncDispatch.java:72)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
```

**- Update1**

Removing  the java & jacoco apply plugins from allprojects allow the test to run:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

allprojects {

    jacoco {
        toolVersion = "0.7.0.201403182114"
        //toolVersion = "0.6.2.201302030002"
        //reportsDir = file("$buildDir/reports/jacocoTest.exec")
    }
}
```

But, in that case: `:jacocoTestReport SKIPPED`

Even with the current code:

```
jacocoTestReport {
        dependsOn test
        group = "Reporting"
        description = "Jacoco coverage reports after running tests."
        ignoreFailures = true

        doFirst {

            rootProject.subprojects.each {
                println it + " JACOCO----->"
                if (new File("${it.sourceSets.main.output.classesDir}").exists()) {
                    logger.debug("Class files: ${it.sourceSets.main.output.classesDir}")
                    if (classDirectories == null) {
                        classDirectories = fileTree(dir: "${it.sourceSets.main.output.classesDir}", includes: jacocoIncludes, excludes: jacocoExcludes)
                    } else {
                        classDirectories += fileTree(dir: "${it.sourceSets.main.output.classesDir}", includes: jacocoIncludes, excludes: jacocoExcludes)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        reports {
            xml.enabled true
            csv.enabled false
            html.destination "$buildDir/jacoco/jacocoHtml"
        }
        //classDirectories = fileTree(dir: "$buildDir/classes/main")
        //sourceDirectories = fileTree(dir: "src/main/java")
        executionData = files("$buildDir/jacoco/jacocoTest.exec")
    }
```

It seems Jacoco plugin is not ready for recursion out of the box... Is there a workaround ?

Thanks

Comment: All that the stack trace tells is that the Gradle test JVM exits with code 255. Perhaps try and isolate the issue (run a single subproject, run a single test, run Gradle with different JDK version, configure different JaCoCo version, etc.).

Comment: I can't find any trace about code 255, what does it mean ?

Comment: As far as I know, it doesn't have a standardized meaning. Not sure who's responsible for returning with this value.

Comment: I've updated the issue with the jacoco plugin configuration: when `allprojects{}` is embedding `apply plugin :'jacoco'` it's raising the error. Not applying the plugin for allprojects or subprojects results in 0% coverage as the root project doesn't have java code..

Comment: The issue affects both versions of JDK1.6 and 1.7. Also tested with large memory settings for $GRADLE_OPTS.